# How to highlight a mat-row if a value changed in the row?

Tags: angular

I have a (table mat-table) in angular, which contains rows (mat-row).
The user can change values in the row by editing them in a dialog box. After saving the value changes, but I want to show the user which row he modified with highlighting it.

I know how to highlight and make background-color in case he focuses on my row with the mouse, or color in different circumstances but this is a new thing for me.

Comment: As soon as the value of the field is changed, set a flag in the .ts file. Based on the flag value, use ngClass to add/remove CSS that highlights the row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked very similar question a while ago and you can see the answer here:

[Angular 2+ - Material Table - Apply dynamically background color to a row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53496808/angular-2-material-table-apply-dynamically-background-color-to-a-row)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

you would need to create some css class for it name it 'RedRow' for example and that class slould do the coloring of background.

in table definition add *matCellDef="let row"

and then in row add

```
mat-row ... [class.RedRow]="Edited(row)"
```

and in code create function Edited(row) that will return true / false based on if this is edited row.