# change background color based on response attributes Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I had request data from API, then I got response Object, so using `*ngFor`, I had managed to display some data that I want, problem is that are some **css** need to be implemented based on response attribute, for my data, I had list of bank and status. based on attribute status **Offline**
I need to change background color and need only show **Offline** status only.I had managed to change the background color, this is what I had tried:

**html file**

```
<ul class="ul1">
  <li 
  [style.background]="getBackgroundColor(p.status)"
   class="li1" *ngFor="let p of myData?.paymentChannels">
  <span>{{p.name}}</span>
  <br>
  <span>{{p.status}}</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**ts file**

```
  getBackgroundColor(status) {
    switch (status) {
      case 'Offline':
      return 'grey';
    }
  }
```

**expected output**:
[image]

also this is my [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3fmy9e?file=src/app/payment/payment.component.html) demo, I could use some suggestion to solve mine.

Comment: Shared stackblitz is working as expected!

Comment: It is not, the OP don't want the 'Active' word on the white tiles that appear on the StackBlitz.

Comment: An similar question was answered here:
[apply dynamically background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53496808/angular-2-material-table-apply-dynamically-background-color-to-a-row)

Comment: @Praetorian1995 The OP just want the status to be displayed if the status is 'Offline', otherwise, don't display the status. The background color change dynamically has been solved by the OP itself.

Comment: @DavidFontes your are right, my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest something like this:

```
<ul class="ul1">
  <li 
  [ngClass]="{offline: p.status == 'Offline'}"
   class="li1" *ngFor="let p of myData?.paymentChannels">
  <span>{{p.name}}</span>
  <br>
  <span> {{p.status == 'Offline' ? p.status : '&nbsp;'}}</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And add to css:

```
.offline {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter your data using structural directive `*ngIf` and then apply styling:

```
<ul
   *ngIf="myData?.paymentChannels" 
    class="ul1">
    <li 
       [style.background]="p?.status === 'Offline'? 'grey' : 'green'"
       class="li1" 
       *ngFor="let p of myData?.paymentChannels">

       <ng-container *ngIf="p?.status === 'Offline'">
           <span>{{p.name}}</span>
           <br>
           <span>{{p.status}}</span>
       </ng-container>
     </li>
</ul>
```

If you want to filter and your array of data is small, then you can use `*ngIf` directive. However, it would be better to use filter pipe:

```
<li *ngFor="let item of myData?.paymentChannels | yourFilter:filterargs">
```

and your pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'myfilter',
    pure: false
})
export class YourFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(items: any[], filter: Object): any {
        if (!items || !filter) {
            return items;
        }
        // filter items array, items which match and return true will be
        // kept, false will be filtered out
        return items.filter(item => item.title.indexOf(filter.title) !== -1);
    }
}
```

and you should include your pipe into `app.module.ts`:

```
import { YourFilterPipe } from './shared/pipes/your-filter.pipe';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ..
    ],
    declarations: [
        YourFilterPipe,
    ],
    providers: [
        ..
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

[Please, see the example at stackblitz.com](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e1gnag?file=src/app/payment/payment.component.html)

**UPDATE:**

If you do not want to filter data, but hide status `offline` you can use `*ngIf` structural directive:

```
<ul
   *ngIf="myData?.paymentChannels" 
    class="ul1">
    <li 
       [style.background]="p?.status === 'Offline'? 'grey' : 'green'"
       class="li1" 
       *ngFor="let p of myData?.paymentChannels">
           <span>{{p.name}}</span>
           <br>
           <span *ngIf="p?.status === 'Offline'; else empty">{{p.status}}</span>
           <ng-template #empty>$nbsp;</ng-template>
     </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi, can you show your solution using filter on stackblitz ?

Comment: @jajanato I've added the link to the stackblitz, please, see my updated answer

Comment: it seems like it only show only 'offline status',  ? mine need to display all the data, but status which is 'offline' need to be shown and hide status which are not 'offline'

Comment: @jajanato yeah, you are right! Sorry for confusion. Please, see my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

your code is working but I think it's better without function like this:

```
<ul class="ul1">
<li [style.background]="'grey' : p.status == 'Offline'" class="li1" 
*ngFor="let p of myData?.paymentChannels">
<span>{{p.name}}</span>
<br>
<span>{{p.status}}</span>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Before**

```
<span>{{p.status}}</span>
```

**After**

```
<span>{{p.status === 'Offline' ? 'Offline' : '&nbsp;'}}</span>
```

It would be even better if you would extract the logic to a method withing the TS file.

The `'&nbsp;'` part is a placeholder (blank space) so the box do not collapse, but I would recommend adding the proper CSS styling, for instance, adding `min-height: 36px;` to the class `.li1` would suffice.

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rdwhuj)