# How to apply angular material style properties based on some conditions?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular8

I have one Enum called status as

```
export const enum Status {
    ACTIVE = "Active",
    REVIEW = "Review"
}
```

And I have a mat-button like

```
<button class="status-button"
                 mat-raised-button  color="warn">{{myObj.realStatus}}</button>
```

**status-button** is my own class and
**color** is the property of angular material.

I want two ways for changing the color based on the enum

Like

1. If Enum is Active I want color warn else primary (that is I want to change the color property of mat button based on the enum condition which I get from myObj)
2. If I can add two classes at same time based on Enum that is additional style along with **status-button**

How can I achieve this in a simpler way hope My question is crystal clear..!!

Comment: Here you have a similar question, you can take ideas from it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53496808/angular-material-table-apply-dynamically-background-color-to-a-row-angular-2

Comment: @Kiril I think there the css is used is custom css here I need to apply a condition for the material UI component property no external css evaluation is needed

Comment: I have modified my answer.. please check..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 <button mat-raised-button
        class="status-button"
        [ngClass]="myObj.realStatus == 'Active' ? 'activeClass' : 'reviewClass'">
        {{myObj.realStatus}}
</button>
```

Since you are giving color and css file based on enum, you could also add the background-color property to your css classes, thereby you could avoid color property from html.

**.css**

```
.activeClass {
  color: black;
  background-color: #f44336;  /*warn*/
}

.reviewClass {
  color: white;
  background-color:#3f51b5;  /*primary*/
}
```

Comment: Umm in the first case I want solution directly in html something like checking myObj.realStatus if its active will apply primary else warn is it possible? As I dont need to create extra variable for styles

Comment: <button mat-raised-button  color="warn">{{myObj.realStatus==="Active"}}</button> I just tried evaluating the expression and its being correctly evaluated offcourse we cant get there enum but we can check like this but any Idea how to put this condition for color property?

Answer (score 3):

1. For this one, implement in the typescript the following:

```
public colorPicked: string = Status.ACTIVE? "warn" : "primary"
```

Next in the HTML replace the color with the new variable you created:

```
button class="status-button"
                 mat-raised-button  color="colorPicked">{{myObj.realStatus}}</button>
```

2. For the second, if I understood correctly, you want to change CSS class basing on the enum. You can use NgClass to pick the class basing on the expression (class1 and class2 are css classes defined in the css file):

```
button [ngClass]="{'class1': Status.ACTIVE, 'class2': Status.REVIEW}">{{myObj.realStatus}}</button>
```

Comment: Umm in the first case I want solution directly in html something like checking myObj.realStatus if its active will apply primary else warn is it possible? As I dont need to create extra variable for styles

Comment: <button mat-raised-button  color="warn">{{myObj.realStatus==="Active"}}</button> I just tried evaluating the expression and its being correctly evaluated offcourse we cant get there enum but we can check like this but any Idea how to put this condition for color property?

Comment: Regarding 1), yes you can avoid using the variable and pass the condition directly in the html.

Comment: <button 
                 mat-raised-button  color="myObj.realStatus==='Active':'warn'?'primary'">{{myObj.realStatus}}</button> I just used this one but the color was not picked up and there is no errors can you help me what is done wrong here?

Comment: Correct this: 
<button mat-raised-button color="myObj.realStatus==='Active'?'warn':'primary'">{{myObj.realStatus}}</button>

Comment: I tried but its not effective I think the myObj.realStatus is not getting checked if I write anything instead of  myObj.realStatus color dosent change and errors arent appearing as well

Comment: Why don't you use typescript?

Comment: I use it in angular for writing logics but want to keep simple like I need to make less use of variables as I can basically I came from java to typescript and also angular is new to me );

Comment: {{question.questionStatus==='Active'}} is being evaluated correctly but for buttons I don't know why and how its not working

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you want to change the color according to a condition. To get there you can use the ngClass and ngStyle directive.

For example:

in your component.html

```
<button [ngClass]="{'defaultClass': true,
                'redClass': condition1 // (ACTIVE),
                'greenClass': condition2  // (REVIEW)}"
    [ngStyle]="{color: getColor()}">
</button>
```

in your component.ts

```
getColor() {
    if (condition1) {
      return 'green';
    } else if(condition2) {
      return 'red';
    }
  }
```

in your component.css

```
.defaultClass{ 
// Your default style
}
.red{ 
// Your style
}

.green{ 
// Your style
}
```